# Typescript generic, how to narrow this type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I'm trying to create generic Props for a React Input component. The expected outcome is that the `onChange` event is correctly typed to either `string` or `number` depending on the `type` of the input, but right now, I can't find a way to narrow it enough. Here is the code:

```
import React, {ChangeEvent, HTMLInputTypeAttribute} from 'react' 

export type InputProps<TypeT extends HTMLInputTypeAttribute> = {
  type: TypeT,
  onChange: (value: TypeT extends 'number' ? number : string) => void
}>

function Input<TypeT extends HTMLInputTypeAttribute>({ type, onChange }: InputProps<TypeT>) {
    const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (type === 'number') {
            onChange(event.currentTarget.valueAsNumber)
        } else {
            onChange(event.currentTarget.value)
        }
    }

    return <input type={type} onChange={handleChange} />
}

<>
  Valid text:
  <Input type="text" onChange={(value: string) => console.log(value)} />
  Valid number:
  <Input type="number" onChange={(value: number) => console.log(value)} />
  Invalid:
  <Input type="text" onChange={(value: number) => console.log(value)} />
</>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you should be using a discriminated union for this instead: https://tsplay.dev/mMzXQW

Comment: Amazing, can you paste it as answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a discriminated union instead could achieve the same behavior while also getting rid of the errors in the implementation. However, since `HTMLInputTypeAttribute` is a union that includes `string & {}`, it's quite difficult to create:

```
type Remove<T, S> = T extends T ? (S extends T ? never : T) : never;

export type InputProps =
    | {
          type: "number";
          onChange: (value: number) => void;
      }
    | {
          type: Remove<Exclude<HTMLInputTypeAttribute, "number">, string & {}>;
          onChange: (value: string) => void;
      };
```

This probably isn't the *best* way to remove `string & {}` (there must be a way to remove `"number" | string & {}` in one go), but this is what I came up with for now. So when you narrow your props based on the type, `onChange` is also properly narrowed:

```
function Input({ type, onChange }: InputProps) {
    const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (type === "number") {
            onChange(event.currentTarget.valueAsNumber); // okay
        } else {
            onChange(event.currentTarget.value); // okay
        }
    };

    return <input type={type} onChange={handleChange} />;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-a73TKvT6kH6A6sMhGuidOiTjJ0dDA3SQ4NZgGqSmYXDgekpExRG8LRfKlAB6eGGE6GayOU4ANWWBxK3llp2sHPrIhcml8Pk0cFbSEb6MDWIhZF1-JIAQgoqdSwgZC3eZ7w86Y6WE4GFqgqRnc56i8fm1X683ubWn5GfcBWPJBT3PS8kAya9Tm4AMDhfTpZzrd8lynb9phZNscAg9IAK2VxnAPI8TzPC8-yguBe0HXsjCAA)